# Управляемый тип в контейнере std::list С++\CLI

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

Хочу программно создать заранее неизвестное количество элементов ComboBox и для дальнейшего использования занести их в std::list<>. Компилятор ругается на управляемый тип:

```
error C3265: нельзя объявлять управляемый '_Myval' в неуправляемом 'std::_List_nod<_Ty,_Alloc>::_Node'
```

Подскажите как можно динамически создать несколько элементов формы?

```
this->Height += 30;
ComboBox^ comboBox = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ComboBox()); 
comboBox->FormattingEnabled = true;
comboBox->Items->AddRange(gcnew cli::array< System::Object^  >(1) {L"TEST"});
comboBox->Location = System::Drawing::Point(48, this->Height-30);
comboBox->Name = StdToSys(string("cbCriterion")+(string)(Conv)++cbIndex);
comboBox->Text = StdToSys(string("cbCriterion")+(string)(Conv)cbIndex);
comboBox->Size = System::Drawing::Size(108, 21);
comboBox->TabIndex = cbIndex;

std::list<ComboBox^> cBox; //собственно строка преткновения
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если Вы используете C++/CLI, то используйте типы .NET. В данном случае есть к примеру тип [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/6sh2ey19.aspx), который по возможностям близкий к требуемому.

Comment: Спасибо, получилось создать список

    System::Collections::Generic::List<ComboBox^> cBox;
    cBox.Add(comboBox);

И сразу появился еще один вопрос. Я хочу использовать этот список в в обработчиках других событий, т.е. надо или передавать через параметры (не знаю как) или глабально объявить (ругается что управляемые типы не могут быть глобальными).

Comment: объявите этот массив как поле класса.

А передавать - также как и обычные типы. Никаких проблем.

    ... mymethod(System::Collections::Generic::List<ComboBox^> box)     
    {
      work with box
    }

    mymethod(cBox);

А вообще, выкиньте этот c++/cli. Лучше либо чистый С++, либо С#.